# Is it possible to write simultaneous score equations for a linear mixed model for the fixed effect, random effect, and variance terms?

Tags: mixed-model

I have been learning about LMMs primarily using this resource:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002437951100320X

In terms of obtaining score equations in this context, it looks like I have two options:

1) If I assume the variance terms are known, I can obtain simultaneous score equations for the fixed and random effect estimates by using the log joint distribution of the outcome and random effect (above equation 7).

2) If I write the marginal distribution of y, I can obtain score equations for the fixed effect and variance estimates (but not the random effect) (equations 17a-c).

My end goal is to find an analytic expression for the variance of a parameter that is a complicated function of the estimated fixed effect terms, random effect terms, and variance terms. To this end, I had hoped to create a sandwich variance estimate to account for variation in my earlier estimates, but that requires identifying simultaneous score equations. Is it even possible to find such equations?

Answer (score 1):

Note also that in standard maximum likelihood theory there are some technical issues in treating the random effects as parameters to be estimated. This is because in standard maximum likelihood you make the assumption that the dimension of the parameter space remains constant as $n \rightarrow \infty$, with $n$ denoting the sample size (i.e., independent sample units). This is violated when you treat the random effects as parameters because for each new sample unit you need new parameters.

As an alternative, you may look at the H-likelihood theory.